# Is there a way to get rid of template <class T> on operator overloading?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of `template <class TI>` to make my code more clear (I have an overload for every logic operator, not only `operator==`). Only in C++98, please.

```
template <class T> 
class iter
{
public:
    // some stuff
private:
    template <class TI>
    friend bool operator == (const iter<TI> &lhs, const iter<TI> &rhs);
};

template <class T>
bool operator == (const iter<T> &lhs, const iter<T> &rhs) {
    return (lhs._ptr == rhs._ptr);
}
```

Comment: What is `iter<TI>` and what does it have to do with `class_name<T>`?

Comment: Don't you simply need: `friend bool operator == (const iter&lhs, const iter&rhs);`?

Comment: I'm re-implementing a vector class, and this class is the iterator class for my vector.  `Operator==` compare 2 iterator

Comment: Your attempt is overtly permissive. It basically says all instantiations of `operator ==` are friended to all instantiations of `iter`, regardless of whether `TI` and `T` are synonymous. If that is what you really want, so be it. If not, get rid of `TI` entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `template<class T> class iter`, you may simply use `iter` to mean `iter<T>`.

```
template <class T> 
class iter
{
public:
    // some stuff
private:
    friend bool operator == (const iter& lhs, const iter& rhs);
    {
        return (lhs._ptr == rhs._ptr);
    }
};
```